# Internal behavior of DateTime.TryParse API regarding date element separator or delimiter

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I was going through `DateTime.TryParse` API in C# .Net. Please look at below code:

```
DateTime dt;
//Behavior # 1 : forward slash date separator
bool parsed = DateTime.TryParse("2016/12/01", out dt); //returns true. Date Value 01 December 2016
//Behavior # 2 : dot date separator
parsed = DateTime.TryParse("2016.12.02", out dt); //returns true. Date Value 02 December 2016
//Behavior # 3 : dot date separator
parsed = DateTime.TryParse("2016-12-03", out dt); //returns true. Date Value 03 December 2016
//Behavior # 4 : comma date separator
parsed = DateTime.TryParse("2016,12,04", out dt); //returns true. Date Value 04 December 2016 
//Behavior # 5 : space date separator
parsed = DateTime.TryParse("2016 12 05", out dt); //returns true. Date Value 05 December 2016
```

First three behaviors are ok with me. I was already aware of `/` and `-` being used as date separators. Today, I came to know that German date time format uses dot `.` as date separator. So I went ahead and tried to investigate as to how the API is able to treat even comma `,` and space  as valid date separator. I wrote following code:

```
var allLanguageDateDelimiters = new List<string>();
foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
{
    if(allLanguageDateDelimiters.All(x => x != ci.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator))
    {
        allLanguageDateDelimiters.Add(ci.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator);
        Console.WriteLine(ci.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator);
    }
}
```

This code prints following characters:

1. / (Forward slash)
2. . (period)
3. -(Hyphen)
4. `.`(period with a trailing space character)

So essentially I iterated all cultures of the world and figured out what all characters are used as delimiter or separator for date field. Then how come the `DateTime.TryParse` API is able to show-up behavior # 4 and 5 where it successfully parses date strings having comma `,` and space  as date separator? Can someone guide me about internal implementation of `DateTime.TryParse` API. My assumption is that it should follow the separator characters of all existing cultures only while parsing a string which is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For white space (), this is *already* [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx) as;

> Any leading, **inner**, or trailing white space character in `s` is ignored.

So, all these;

```
DateTime.TryParse("2016               12 05", out dt);
DateTime.TryParse("         2016 12 05", out dt);
DateTime.TryParse("2016 12 05        ", out dt);
```

returns `true`.

But why comma? I think that's because [`TokenType`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,5052) enum's [`SEP_Space`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,5076) member defined with white space and comma *internally*. This enumeration was using by the [`Lex`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,600) method in [`TryParse`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,2330) to tokenize the current character in the string with calling [`GetSeparatorToken`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,4490) method.

```
// Separator tokens.
..
..
SEP_Space      = 0x300,    // Whitespace (including comma).
```

Comment: This suggests they have included this support (for comma) explicitly for parsing only even though it is not being used as a separator while representing dates in any of the cultures. This might attribute to CSV and TSV being a famous format used to store data in files.

Answer (score 1):

I think `,` and (space) is intentionally used for these kind of formats.

```
"Fri, 15 May 2009 20:10:57 GMT"
```

Repeating of these characters are also ignored. for example

```
"2016,, , ,12,,  ,  03"
```

Will parse happily.